Various Ways to Prove the Half-Angle Formulae for Sine and Cosine
I was pondering about the different methods by which the half-angle identities for sine and cosine can be proved.
$$\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}$$
$$\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}$$
Besides the standard method (which uses the double angle formula for cosine), I have thought of $3$ others: the first being a geometrical method involving a circle, the second involving Euler's formula and the third involving vectors as elaborated below in my answer.

Are there any other creative ways to prove these identities?

Using the Double Angle Formula for Cosine
$$\cos x=2\cos^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)-1=1-2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)$$
$$\implies\cos^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)=\frac{1+\cos x}2, \sin^2\left(\frac{x}2\right)=\frac{1-\cos x}2$$
$$\implies\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}, \left|\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}$$

What about using the power series for $\sin$ and $\cos$?

@Sahaj I tried it but it just kept getting lengthy and tedious. I’ll try once again and find a pattern later.

@MathGuy I've suggested another way using Euler's identity which looks more simpler to me. Let me know your thought on that, if it doesn't help, I'll delete it. Thanks, bye

This is not a question.  This is a question, plus several answers.  Use the question box for questions, and the answer box for answers.

@XanderHenderson these are my attempts for the question. If I don’t post these along with the question, wouldn’t the question be downvoted badly?

@MathGuy I have no idea.  But your motivation should be to ask a good question, not to avoid downvotes.  And please keep in mind that "attempts" are not (in my opinion) good context.  They are minimal context for people who don't really know any better.  Context should explain why a problem is interesting or worth answering.

@MathGuy Moderators have no ability to remove downvotes.

To those downvoting, I guess you’re doing so since I didn’t show my work enough; please scroll down, I have presented my methods in the form an answer as it is not suitable for them to be in the question body.

The double-angle formulas are completely equivalent to the half-angle formulas. A simpler approach, starting from Euler's formula, involves first proving the double-angle formula fo $\cos$
$$\cos (2x)+i\sin (2x)=e^{i2x}=e^{ix}e^{ix}=(\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x)+i(2\sin x \cos x)$$
from this, we derive the half-angle formula for $\cos$
$$\cos (2x)=\cos^2 x-\sin^2 x =2\cos^2 x -1 \implies \cos x=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2x)}2}$$
The corresponding half-angle formula for
$\sin$ can then be obtained directly by using the shifting angle trigonometric identity
$$\sin (2x)=\cos \left(\frac \pi 2 -2x\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(\pi -x)}2}=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}$$

A standard approach is rotation matrices. Recall that
$$
\newcommand{\m}[1]{\begin{bmatrix} #1 \end{bmatrix}}
\newcommand{\r}[1]{\m{\cos #1 & -\sin #1 \\ \sin #1 & \cos #1}}
R_\theta := \r \theta
$$
encodes a rotation by $\theta$ radians. Hence, clearly,
$$
R_\theta R_\varphi = R_{\theta+\varphi}
$$
so in particular
$$
\r{\frac \theta 2}^2 =  R_{\theta/2} R_{\theta/2} = R_\theta = \r \theta
$$
Since
$$
\r{\frac \theta 2}^2
= \m{\cos^2 \frac \theta 2 - \sin^2\frac \theta 2 & -2 \cos \frac \theta 2 \sin \frac \theta 2 \\
2 \cos \frac \theta 2 \sin \frac \theta 2 & \cos^2 \frac \theta 2 - \sin^2\frac \theta 2}
$$
you can then solve the system of equations
$$
\left\{ \begin{align*}
\cos^2 \frac \theta 2 - \sin^2\frac \theta 2 &= \cos \theta \\
2 \cos \frac \theta 2 \sin \frac \theta 2 &= \sin \theta
\end{align*}
\right.
$$
in any of your usual, preferred ways to conclude the formula.

A similar approach can be done with the complex rotations, as $e^{i \theta}$ encodes a rotation by $\theta$ radians about the origin in the complex plane. (In fact, using a representation of complex numbers as
$$
x+iy \longrightarrow \m{x & -y \\ y & x}
$$
it is identical.)

Recall the power series:
$$\cos(x) = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\underbrace{\color{blue}{\frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}x^{2r}}}_{a_r}$$
Via the Cauchy Product of two infinite series:
$$\begin{aligned}
\cos^2(x) &= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{r} \color{blue}{a_ka_{r-k}} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \sum_{k=0}^{r} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2k)!(2r-2k)!}x^{2r} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!} x^{2r}\sum_{k=0}^{r} \frac{(2r)!}{(2k)!(2r-2k)!} \\
&= \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!} x^{2r}\sum_{k=0}^{r} \binom{2r}{2k}
\end{aligned}$$
At this point we're concerned with the sum $S = \sum_{k=0}^r \binom{2r}{2k}$. This can be combinatorially interpreted as the number of subsets of a $2r$-set with an even number of elements. If the set is the empty set the count is $1$ which is the empty set itself; if the set is non-empty the count is $2^{2r-1}$. Thus one can write:
$$\begin{align}
\cos^2(x) &= 1+\sum_{\color{red}{r=1}}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!} x^{2r} \cdot 2^{2r-1}\\
&= 1 + \frac12\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}(2x)^{2r} \\
&= 1 + \frac12\left(\left(\sum_{\color{red}{r=0}}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^r}{(2r)!}(2x)^{2r}\right) - 1\right) \\
&= 1 + \frac12(\cos(2x) - 1) \\
\cos^2(x) &= \frac{\cos(2x)}2 + \frac12
\end{align}$$
Now transforming $x\mapsto \frac{x}2$ gives the desired identity. With this one can easily derive the one for $\sin$ by transforming $x\to \frac{\pi}2-x$.

You can use the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem for coupled IVPs:
Each pair satisfies the coupled Initial Value Problem
\begin{align*} u' &= \frac{v}{2},\ &u(\pi/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\\v' &=-\frac{u}{2},\ &v(\pi/2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\end{align*}
Each coupled IVP has a unique solution pair (subject to some constraints which are satisfied here for $0<x<2\pi$), and so the pair $$\left(\left|\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right|,\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right| \right)$$ and the pair $$\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}{2}},\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}{2}}\right)$$ match.
Though definitely the LONG way around, you can prove all sorts of pairs of related trigonometric identities in this way.

$\textbf{1.}$ Using Congruent Triangles in a Circle and the Cosine Rule
This method proves the identities for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ only since the minimum and the maximum angles that can be subtended by an arc of a circle at its centre are $0($limiting case of a point$)$ and $\pi($semi-circular arc$)$ respectively.

Let $\angle AOB=\theta$. Now, in $\Delta OAD$ and $\Delta OBD$,
$$\angle ODA=\angle ODB=90^{\circ}$$
$$OA=OB=R$$
$$OD\text{ is common}$$
$\therefore\text{By the RHS congruency criterion, }\Delta OAD\cong \Delta OBD\implies \angle AOD=\angle BOD=\frac{\theta}2$

The length of $AB$ can be derived in $2$ ways:

i) By basic trigonometry,
$$AB=2R\sin\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)$$
ii) By the cosine rule,
$$AB^2=OA^2+OB^2-2\cdot OA\cdot OB\cos\theta$$
$$\implies AB^2=2R^2-2R^2\cos\theta$$
$$\implies AB=R\sqrt{2(1-\cos\theta)}$$
$$\therefore\sin\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}2}$$

Similarly, the length of $OD$ can also be derived in $2$ ways:

i) By basic trigonometry,
$$OD=R\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)$$
ii) By the Pythagorean theroem,
$$OD=\sqrt{OA^2-AD^2}$$
$$\implies OD=\sqrt{R^2-\frac{R^2}2(1-\cos\theta)}$$
$$\implies OD=R\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}2}$$
$$\therefore\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}2}$$
$\textbf{2.}$ Using Euler's Formula
$$\cos x=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$$
$$\implies\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}=\sqrt{\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}+2}4},\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}=\sqrt{\frac{2-e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}4}$$
$$\implies\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{e^{ix/2}+e^{-ix/2}}2\right)^2}, \sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}=\sqrt{\left(\frac{e^{ix/2}-e^{-ix/2}}{2i}\right)^2}$$
$$\implies\left|\cos\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos x}2}, \left|\sin\left(\frac{x}2\right)\right|=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos x}2}$$
$\textbf{3.}$ Using Vectors
This method also proves the identities for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ only since the angle between $2$ vectors ranges from $0($parallel vectors$)$ to $\pi($anti-parallel vectors$)$.
Let vectors $\vec{a_1}$ and $\vec{a_2}$ have the same magnitude $a$ with an angle $\theta$ between them. Let their resultant vector on addition be $\vec{A}$ of magnitude $A$.

The expression for $A$ can be obtained in $2$ ways:

i) By directly using the formula
$$\left|\vec{a}+\vec{b}\right|=\sqrt{|\vec{a}|^2+ |\vec{b}|^2+ 2|\vec{a}||\vec{b}|\cos\theta}\text{ (where }\theta\text{ is the angle between }\vec{a}\text{ and }\vec{b})\tag1$$
we get
$$A=\sqrt{a^2+a^2+2a\cdot a\cos\theta}$$
$$\implies A=a\sqrt{2(1+\cos\theta)}$$
ii) By taking components

Hence,
$$A=2a\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)$$
$$\therefore\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}2}$$

Now, consider $\frac12\vec{A}$ and $\vec{a_1}-\frac12\vec{A}$. Let $\left|\vec{a_1}-\frac12\vec{A}\right|=B$.


i) Using the Pythagorean theorem(can be thought of as a special case of $(1)$,
$$B^2+\frac{A^2}4=a^2$$
$$\implies B^2+\frac{a^2(1+\cos\theta)}2=a^2$$
$$\implies B^2=\frac{a^2(1-\cos\theta)}2$$
$$\implies B=a\sqrt{\frac{(1-\cos\theta)}2}$$
ii) From the vector diagram where we took components of vectors,
$$B=a\sin\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)$$
$$\therefore\sin\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)=\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \theta}2}$$
